# Do TreeMaps automatically sort keys?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, treemap

While using a HashMap to store a Player object and an Integer, I got stuck while sorting the HashMap and was recommended to use a TreeMap, after reading some of the documentation it seems that it sorts the map based off of the keys put in.

So theoretically, if I made the TreeMap as  it would sort the map for me?

Comment: That's the whole point of `TreeMap`'s existence.

Comment: Yep, that's how it works.

Comment: @Slaw And O(log n) worst case access.

Comment: @Tom As I understand it though, `HashMap` has the same worst case since Java 8, at least when the keys are comparable.

Comment: Javadoc of [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html): *"The map is **sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys**, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used."* --- I'm confused as to why you're asking this question if you already read the documentation. That quote is from the **very first paragraph of the documentation**.

Comment: @Slaw Depends upon the type of the objects and is implementation specific. Also, that update was significantly predated by `TreeMap`.

Comment: @Morinator Some effort on the asker's part (i.e., a cursory look at documentation for what they're working with) is a requirement to ask questions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you call `yourmap.keySet().iterator()`, it returns the elements in ascending order based on the keys. This is either their natural order or a comparator that you defined.
Internally, it will propably use [Inorder-Traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) like this:
[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal]

You see, that on the left subtree of each node the values are smaller and on the right side they are bigger. Therefore, if you first list the elements on the left, then the node itself, then all on the right, you have it in ascending order. If you apply this rule for every node recursively, you receive your wanted iterator.

You can find an example on how to use this in Java [here](https://beginnersbook.com/2014/07/how-to-iterate-treemap-in-reverse-order-in-java/).

Remember that a HashMap has a lookup of O(1), but a TreeMap has O(log(n)). Unless you rely on the ordering of keys, you should favor HashMap becase it's faster.

Comment: A TreeMap does not have an `iterator()` method.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap-s don't make any guarantee on element ordering. However a TreeMap is implemented as a tree structure. (a red-black tree, which would be near-balanced). Elements are stored and traversed in order. Retrieval complexity is O(log n), compared to the HashMap's O(1).

Comment: Weirdly enough, it is specified in JavaDoc: "A Red-Black tree based NavigableMap implementation."